# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was looping through two nested arrays and if some necessary fields are empty then I just Update the error object but it's giving me an error: **Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions**

```
  let error = { message: '' }

        currentTaskList.sections.forEach(element1 => {
            element1.tasks.forEach(element2 => {
                if (element2.requireImage || element2.requireText) {
                    !element2.input ? error.message = 'Please Fill all necessary Fields' : null
                    !element2.image && element2.requireImage ? error.message = 'Please Fill all necessary Fields' : null
                }
            })
        })
```

Comment: You're using a conditional operator as an "inline `if`" which your linter rules disallow. Just...use a normal `if`. The "inline `if`" thing is an abomination and should be burned out of existence anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ can u explain a bit more or just change the code and give me the solutions so that I can go through And try to understand. I don't know what does that mean by inline if.

Comment: `!element2.input ? error.message = 'Please Fill all necessary Fields' : null` -> `if(!element2.input) error.message = 'Please Fill all necessary Fields'` it's shorter than using the conditional operator `? :`  anyway

Comment: @VLAZ your answer is absolutely correct. how can I make your comment as the correct answer?